# Mongoose schema change (with _id change)

Tags: mongodb, schema, mongoose, ref, objectid

I have a schema named card to update 
from `{_id: ObjectId, id: String, ....}`
to `{_id: String(same as id), id: String, ....}`

and update also a schema named users which is like 
`{name: String, email: string, cards: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'card'}}`

how can i do this ?

Comment: Why do you want to store the id as a string? How much data are we talking about? Can you afford a little downtime? If we're talking about small amounts of data and downtime is ok, the easiest approach would be a migration script that essentially copies the data but changes a few fields.

Comment: I can have 15min as downtime, but i have like 1000 user to update, which can contains multiple ref to card in different place (subdoc, etc...). I want to use the string because i want to populate myself (as all cards go into ram when the server launch, to improve performance)

Comment: using string to improve performance sounds like a strange idea, but it probably doesn't matter. Updating 1000 users should take less than one second, so I'd go for a migration script. Take the server offline, run the script, change the code, start the server. Make sure that everything is tested before.

Comment: This is the last solution i've in mind, i wish it could exist a simpler one with some mongoose script

Comment: What's the difference between a script and a script?

Comment: yeah, a script less complexe and more easy to write :)